# Relocating checkmarks in TableView multiple selection during Edit Mode

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, multipleselection, editmode

Below code provides a blue tick-mark at the left side of myCell when it is selected:

```
myTable.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
myTable.setEditing(true, animated: false)
```

Is there any way I can change its frame? I want it to appear at the bottom-right corner of myCell